# Backbone.js:"Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: backbone.js, document, mousemove

suppose I have a model and a view ,ths view have two method:one is bind the document mousemove event and the other is unbind method,defalut I give the document mousemove event, once the model's `enable` value changed I will call the view's unbind method:

```
    window.ConfigModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'enable':0
        },
        initialize: function(){
            this.bind("change:enable", function () {
                var portView2 = new PortView();
                portView2.viewOff();                        
            });
        },
        change:function () {
            this.set('enable', 9);
        }
     })

    window.PortView = Backbone.View.extend({
        viewOn: function () {
            $(document).on('mousemove', function () {
                console.log('move')
            })
        },
        viewOff: function () {
            $(document).off('mousemove');
        }
    })
```

then I put an `input` on the document to call the model changed:

```
    $('input').click(function () {
        var configModel = new ConfigModel();
        configModel.change();
    })
```

the boot script is :

```
var portView1 = new PortView();
portView1.viewOn();
```

The problem is once I call the click the input button ,the chrome would tell me an error:`Maximum call stack size exceeded` it seems the `change` be invoke many times.So what's the problem with my problem ,how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone models already have a [`change` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-change):

> **change** `model.change()`
>
> Manually trigger the `"change"` event and a `"change:attribute"` event for each attribute that has changed. If you've been passing `{silent: true}` to the set function in order to aggregate rapid changes to a model, you'll want to call `model.change()` when you're all finished.

Presumably something inside Backbone is trying to call `configModel.change()` and getting your version of `change` which triggers another `change()` call inside Backbone which runs your `change` which ... until the stack blows up.

You should use a different name for your `change` method.

---

That said, your code structure is somewhat bizarre. A model listening to events on itself is well and good but a model creating a view is odd:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bind("change:enable", function () {
        var portView2 = new PortView();
        portView2.viewOff();                        
    });
}
```

And instantiating a view simply to call a single method and then throw it away is strange as is creating a new model just to trigger an event.

I think you probably want to have a single ConfigModel instance as part of your application state, say `app.config`. Then your `click` handler would talk to that model:

```
$('input').click(function () {
    app.config.enable_level_9(); // or whatever your 'change' gets renamed to
});
```

Then you'd have some other part of your application (not necessarily a view) that listens for changes to `app.config` and acts appropriately:

```
app.viewOn = function() {
    $(document).on('mousemove', function() {
        console.log('move')
    });
};
app.viewOff = function() {
    $(document).off('mousemove');
};
app.init = function() {
    app.config = new ConfigModel();
    app.viewOn();
    $('input').click(function () {
        app.config.enable_level_9();
    });
    // ...
};
```

And then start the application with a single `app.init()` call:

```
$(function() {
    app.init();
});
```

Comment: I have change the method name, the first problem have changed.But another problem is :the viewOff method does't work,it can't unbind the document's mousemove event, how can I solve this?Use console.log  I can see the method have be invoked ,but just can not unbind

Comment: @hh54188: Renaming `change` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b7rUT/ You still have a strange application structure but it works.